# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: error in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am doing a reader application,which can sync text to googledoc,i got the working sample code of text sync to googledoc,but i put all the code to my project except delegate code,i got this error,

```
Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ELTouchBible-eqhoridwhfpkcvddemynmhjrvyor/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Bible.app/Bible normal i386
    cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/bible day updates/ELTouchBiblelatest3 doingggg copy 11"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ELTouchBible-eqhoridwhfpkcvddemynmhjrvyor/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/admin/Desktop/bible day updates/ELTouchBiblelatest3 doingggg copy 11/Classes" -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ELTouchBible-eqhoridwhfpkcvddemynmhjrvyor/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ELTouchBible-eqhoridwhfpkcvddemynmhjrvyor/Build/Intermediates/ELTouchBible.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Bible.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bible.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -lxml2 -lsqlite3.0 -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -lOAuth -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ELTouchBible-eqhoridwhfpkcvddemynmhjrvyor/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Bible.app/Bible

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_DebugLog", referenced from:
      -[NSData(IdleLoop) dataDecodeFromHtml] in IdleLoop.o
      -[NSData(IdleLoop) dataEncodeToHtml] in IdleLoop.o
      -[GoogleDocs fRetryCachedQuery] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs retitleNextFile] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs downloadEntry:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs uploadFileTicket:failedWithError:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs uploadFileTicket:finishedWithEntry:] in GoogleDocs.o
      ...
  "_Assert", referenced from:
      -[NSData(IdleLoop) dataEncodeToHtml] in IdleLoop.o
      -[GoogleDocs sendFailureNotice:code:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs docListListFetchTicket:failedWithError:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFolderCheck:createIfNeeded:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFileDeleteTitle:inFolder:keepingNewest:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginFileRetitleFrom:toTitle:inFolder:] in GoogleDocs.o
      -[GoogleDocs beginDownloadTitle:inFolder:] in GoogleDocs.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _AssertSelectorNilOrImplementedWithArguments)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but the sample projects works well in xcode 4,i am using xcode4.How to solve this error.please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check dependencies, and check the architecture for the application.

Comment: @Legolas sir can you please explain?

Comment: Please check the build settings and the dependencies. YOu can check them off if you click the project.

Comment: @Legolas Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
now i got this error.

Comment: Can you give the site where you have downloaded the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that the _DebugLog and _Assert functions weren't compiled to work on the simulator.

Look through the code to see where your _DebugLog and _Assert functions are defined in code.  If you can't find them, create something that should match their behavior.  If you do find them, make sure the file they live in is included when building for the simulator.

I hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: @Micheal Dautermann Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
i got this error now

Comment: sounds like you are narrowing in on it. I hope my original answer to you makes sense. You just need to get _DebugLog and _Assert somehow compiled into your simulator app.  If you can't find where they're defined, create your own.